# CSS hover element pushes away other divs and layout

Tags: css, html, hover, mousehover

Problem: When hover over box1 it should expand without affecting other divs and the document layout but my current code push down the box2 div.

i want box1 to be expend over the box2 without affecting its position.

any help please!

[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4ukh/ybhg9qu2/)

```
<div class = "box1">
    <p>first box</p>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="box2">
    <p>2nd box</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box1{
    height: 250px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid darkgray; 
    position: relative;   
}

.box1:hover{
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.box2{
    height: 150px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` with `.box1` in a `relative` parent

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
}
.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  position: relative;
}

.box1:hover {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box2 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box1">
    <p>first box</p>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
      <li>item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <p>2nd box</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `height:400px` on `box1:hover` effect. it's expand `box1` div and push `box2`.

```css
.box1{
    height: 250px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    position: relative;
}

.box1:hover{
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.box2{
    height: 150px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class = "box1">
    <p>first box</p>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="box2">
    <p>2nd box</p>
</div>
```

Comment: but he want this div to expand on hover, so your answer is unhelpful

Answer (score 0):

Just add "margin-bottom: -150px" to styles for hover effect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to have box2 fixed at a position, you need to set position: absolute
and set the top of box2 to some value and left to some value. So, no matter what, box2 wont change its position. If position is relative, box2's position will vary, and it will depend on other elements of the page (box1 in this case). Do the following changes :

```
.box2{
    height: 150px;
    width: 400px;
    top: 300px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Set top and left as per your requirements. The above changed CSS, will not move box2.
Hope this helps .

Comment: sorry for the insufficient information. yes it want box1 to overlap box2.